# Azure ServiceBus Topic Silently Fails Delivery to Subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm running into a very frustrating issue with using an instance of Azure Service Bus. Specifically, I have a topic set up named "commands" which, after a period of time, will stop correctly proxying messages to its subscriptions. I've observed the following behavior that has left me in my presently baffled state:

1. This will only happen after the topic has been in existence for a time, generally overnight. Everything will be working in the evening, but when I return in the morning the topic has ceased functioning and the only solution seems to be to delete and recreate it.
2. As shown in the image below, the topic DOES seem to be receiving the messages as I receive no exceptions after sending and the "Active Message Count" and "Size In Bytes" properties on the topic do increase. It just doesn't send the message to the subscription: [image]
3. I thought that perhaps the filters on my subscriptions were messinging things up, so to test this I deleted those subscriptions and made a new one through the explorer with the default filter. After doing this I sent some new messages through the topic, but they were still not received by the new subscription.
4. I have other topics running on the service bus (such as "events" in the above image), but they don't seem to be exhibiting the same behavior. They are configured in an identical manner, but run just fine.

I'm open to any theories about what might be causing such weird behavior. I'm happy to provide additional information if that helps solve this.

Code blocks:

Create Topic:

```
private async Task<bool> CreateTopicAsync(NamespaceManager namespaceManager, string topicName, CancellationToken cancel, TimeSpan maxWaitTime)
        {
            var retVal = false;
            var maxTimeToCreateTopic = DateTime.UtcNow + maxWaitTime;

            while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested && DateTime.UtcNow < maxTimeToCreateTopic)
            {
                try
                {
                    await namespaceManager.CreateTopicAsync(new TopicDescription(topicName)
                    {
                        EnableBatchedOperations = true,
                        EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing = true
                    });
                    retVal = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogError("Exception thrown when creating topic: {0}", ex);
                }

                if (!retVal)
                {
                    LogWarning("Topic still does not exist, pausing and then retrying creation.");
                    await Task.Delay(_delayMs);
                }
            }

            return retVal;
        }
```

Create Subscription:

```
private async Task<bool> CreateSubscriptionAsync(NamespaceManager namespaceManager, string topicName, string subscriptionName, string filter, CancellationToken cancel, TimeSpan maxWaitTime)
        {
            var retVal = false;
            var maxTimeToCreateSubscription = DateTime.UtcNow + maxWaitTime;

            while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested && DateTime.UtcNow < maxTimeToCreateSubscription)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
                    {
                        namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName, new SqlFilter(filter));
                    }
                    retVal = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogError("Exception thrown when creating subscription: {0}", ex);
                }

                LogWarning("Subscription still does not exist, pausing and then retrying creation.");
                await Task.Delay(_delayMs);
            }

            return retVal;
        }
```

Send Messages To Topic:

```
BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage = null;
                    try
                    {
                        var type = nextMessage.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
                        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nextMessage);
                        var jsonStream = jsonString.ToStream();

                        brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(jsonStream, true);
                        brokeredMessage.Properties["__messageType__"] = type;
                        if (nextData.Properties != null && nextData.Properties.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var prop in nextData.Properties)
                            {
                                brokeredMessage.Properties.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        LogError("Exception thrown when creating brokered message: {0}", ex);

                        brokeredMessage = null;
                    }

                    if (brokeredMessage != null)
                    {
                        var messageSentSuccessfully = false;
                        try
                        {
                            await client.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
                            numConsecutiveFailures = 0;
                            messageSentSuccessfully = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            numConsecutiveFailures++;
                            LogError("Exception thrown from SendAsync: {0}. Fail count is {1}.", ex, numConsecutiveFailures);
                            await Task.Delay(_delayMs);
                        }
                    }
```

Passed in topic client is just created with the TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString method.

Receive Messages From Subscription:

```
private async Task ReceiveLoopAsync(SubscriptionClient client, CancellationToken cancel, TimeSpan maxReceiveWaitTime)
        {
            var numConsecutiveFailures = 0;
            var maxConsecutiveFailures = 5;

            while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested && numConsecutiveFailures < maxConsecutiveFailures)
            {
                BrokeredMessage newMsg = null;

                try
                {
                    newMsg = await client.ReceiveAsync(maxReceiveWaitTime);
                    numConsecutiveFailures = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    numConsecutiveFailures++;
                    LogError("Exception thrown from ReceiveAsync: {0}. Fail count is {1}.", ex, numConsecutiveFailures);
                    await Task.Delay(_delayMs);
                }

                // newMsg will be null if there were no messages to process after the allotted timeout expired.
                if (newMsg != null)
                {
                    // Just a function call.
                    _onMessageReceived?.Invoke(newMsg);
                }

                //LogDebug("Bottom of Receive");
            }

            //LogDebug("Exit Receive");
        }
```

Passed in subscription client is just created with the SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString method.

Comment: Yes Nathan. Can you provide the code showing how you create youtlr topic subscription. Also code to show how you send message and how you receive messages

Comment: I add some of the relevant code blocks to the original post. However, it's worth noting that once the topic gets into its funky state, even using Service Bus Explorer to create a new sub on the topic and send messages to it will exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: @NathanG do you get any exceptions logged by your subscriber or by SBExplorer when a topic is getting into this state? At that point, do you receive any messages at all in your application?

Comment: As stated in the original posts, there are no exceptions caused by sending, as the messages are still apparently getting into the topic as shown by the increase in "active message count" and "size in bytes" variables. Once in this state, I no longer receive any messages from subscriptions tied to this specific topic (even if the messages are sent via the SBExplorer and received by an SBExplorer-created subscription). Other topics / subscriptions work as expected.